# MySQL(i?) Filter on an existing query

Tags: php, mysql, filter

I want to create a filter which filters my ouput from the database. I have no idea how to create this. I have searched some other topics but they were not so helpful, hopefully someone can help me out.

I have the following code which retrieves the information from my database and ouputs it into a table. (please ignore the table set-up and such, still need to clean the nesting and stuff..)

Code (retrieve.php):

```
<?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("xx", "xx", "xx") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("xx") or die(mysql_error());

// SQL query
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM informatie ORDER BY id DESC;";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
```

//OUDE LOOP SPACE

```
   // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)
  echo "<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0'><tr style='background-color:#f04d44; color:#ffffff;'>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Klant</strong></td><td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Datum</strong></td><td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Eventviewer Nagekeken</strong></td><td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Eventviewer Opmerkingen</strong></td><td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Services Nagekeken</strong></td><td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Services Opmerkingen</strong></td><td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Backup Nagekeken</strong></td><td style='border-right:1px solid #ff9a88;'><strong>Backup Opmerkingen</strong></td><td><strong>Check Gedaan Door</strong></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  // Loop the recordset $rs
  // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
  echo "<tr style='background-color:#ffffff;'>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>"; 
  echo $row['klant'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['datum'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['eventviewer_nagekeken'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['eventviewer_opmerkingen'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['services_nagekeken'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['services_opmerkingen'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['backup_nagekeken'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-right:1px solid #cccccc; border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['backup_opmerkingen'];
  echo "</td>";
  echo "<td style='border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;'>";
  echo $row['check_door'];
  echo "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr></table>";

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
```

?>

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Glenn, please don't use mysql_* functions anymore and move to mysqli or pdo for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) reason.

Comment: what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

For filtering, most of the time you can use your database.
Right now your SQL statement is like this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM informatie ORDER BY id DESC;";
```

To filter on information from the table `informatie`, you should alter the SQL statment, for example:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM informatie WHERE `eventviewer_nagekeken` = 1 ORDER BY id DESC;";
```

This will return all rows where `eventviewer_nagekeken` equals 1. This way you will be able to create various outputs from the pool of data you have in the `informatie` table.
For documentation and examples, see the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/).

Comment: Hello! Thanks for replying. I understand the MySQL statement! However, how can I make a PHP button (<a href...) so I can add a filter on-demand?

Comment: To add a filter on demand, you could use HTML, PHP and forms like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp). But you've got multiple options, like [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can use where clause generated dynamically as bellow

```
    $where = ' 1=1 ';
    if(isset($_REQUEST['param1']))
    {
        $where .= " and db_field1 = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['param1']);
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['param2']))
    {
       $where .= " and db_field2 = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['param2']);
    }
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM informatie ".$where." ORDER BY id DESC;";
```

here mysql_real_escape_string will avoid mysql injection.

Hope this helps you.